# C program shows no error but doesn't show output

Tags: c

Roy wants to change his profile picture on Facebook. Now Facebook has some restriction over the dimension of picture that we can upload.
Minimum dimension of the picture can be L x L, where L is the length of the side of square.

Now Roy has N photos of various dimensions.
Dimension of a photo is denoted as W x H 
where W - width of the photo and H - Height of the photo

When any photo is uploaded following events may occur:

1. If any of the width or height is less than L, user is prompted to upload another one. Print "UPLOAD ANOTHER" in this case.
2. If width and height are both large enough and 
   (a) if the photo is already square then it is accepted. Print "ACCEPTED" in this case.
   (b) else user is prompted to crop it. Print "CROP IT" in this case.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
     int len; /* len is the length of the side of square */
     scanf("%d",&len); 

     int test;
     scanf("%d",&test);

     while(test--)
     {
         int w,h; 
         /* w - width of the photo and h- Height of the photo */

         scanf("%d %d",&w,&h);

         if(w==len && h==len)
         {
             printf("ACCEPTED\n");
         }
         else if(w>len || w==len && h>len || h==len)
         {
             printf("CROP IT\n");
         }
         else
         {
             printf("UPLOAD ANOTHER\n");/* print */
         }
     }

     return 0;/* success */
}
```

Comment: Gosh, please ident adequately your code. It will makes things way eaasier for us and you.

Comment: Please provide the input values. And when you say "doesn't show output" do you mean there is no output at all or it doesn't show the output that you expect? Finally, rather than ask someone else to debug for you it will be more beneficial to you if you learn to debug effectively - specifically, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: it's running man . just put getch() at the end before return

Comment: Don't forget to check that input operations worked.  For example, if you typed `250 x 325` for the size, you'd be in trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is that you're seeing no output at all, it's likely because it's running in an IDE and the output window is closing before you can see it. Judicious use of a `getchar()` at the end of `main()` may be all you need to fix this, though I'd probably prefer to just run it from the command line.

In any case, since `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, your second condition is effectively:

```
else if ((w > len) || (w == len && h > len) || (h == len))
```

which is clearly wrong since having a photo with width more than what was necessary would result in a request for cropping *regardless* of the other sub-conditions.

You would be better off following the textual specs more closely so that you can actually check it more easily. That would entail something like (with slightly simplified specs still meeting the original intent):

- If any of the width or height is less than `L`, user is prompted to upload another one.
- Otherwise both are large enough. If the photo is already square then it is accepted.
- Otherwise user is prompted to crop it.

The code for that is a much simpler:

```
if ((w < len) || (h < len)) {
    puts ("UPLOAD ANOTHER");
} else if (h == w) {    // Both large enough otherwise previous
    puts ("ACCEPTED");  //   condition would have been true.
} else {
    puts ("CROP IT");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence),

```
    else if(w>len || w==len && h>len || h==len)
```

is equivalent to:

```
    else if(w>len || (w==len && h>len) || h==len)
```

What you need to use is:

```
    else if( (w>len || w==len) && (h>len || h==len) && (w == h) )
```

You can simplify that to:

```
    else if( w >= len  && h >= len && w == h )
```

which can be further simplified to:

```
    else if( w >= len  && w == h )
```

Comment: there is an else, no matter what ... it will give an output if ever.

Comment: @jace, I doubt that there is no output. I think the OP is not getting the output they are expecting.

Comment: Or simplify it further to `else if (w >=len && w == h)` or, since the previous check has *already* established both `h` and `w` are big enough, `else if (w == h)` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to go to file>preferences>settings>type 'coderunner'> check 'run in terminal'

i was searching up for a similar issue and solved it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It will show output but the program runs faster than you expect. It will close as soon as the output is displayed . It will not wait till you read it.
So use `getch();` declared in `conio.h` to get a single key press as input after you have printed all the output (right before the `return` statement. It will make the program wait for the user to press a key before exiting.

Comment: There is neither a `conio.h` nor a `getch()` in C, despite the penchant for Indian educational institutions to continue teaching people with dead technology :-)

Answer (score -1):

here is the screenshot. it is running without error on me.

**NOTE:** This is not an answer. But this is just the only way to give picture example :) no need to up

[image]

Maybe you only need to put `getchar();` at the end of the code before return to let the screen to pause for a while. it is just exiting very fast